# transaction and execution costs on Remix

Tags: transactions, execution, remix

I am executing smart contracts on Remix and I am getting transaction cost the same as the execution cost which is not supposed to be. I ran many smart contracts and for all Remix is giving the same value for both transaction and execution costs?  why and how is this possible?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5812/what-is-the-difference-between-transaction-cost-and-execution-cost-in-remix

Comment: Please clarify your question as `transaction and execution costs are equal on remix`